# how to opn jnlp files automatically after download

Tags: macos, java

I need to open JNLP files automatically after download just like in windows how can I do that I'm using OS X Mavericks

Answer (score 6):

You could try this

- right click a jnlp file
- chose "Open With"
- select "Other"
- navigate to "System", "Library", "CoreServices"
- scroll the list and pick "Java Web Start" (you may need to chose "Enable All Applications" in order to make that choice possible.
- tick the "Always Open With" box.

It is not recommended to have a generic set up to open files downloaded from the web.

But you can set up a exception.

Specify the Folder for the jnpl files download.

Then create a Folder action to

1- monitor for new files

2-open them

Comment: but still its not opening automatically after download

Comment: For security reason that is blocked. But it depends, so which Browser do you use for download?

Comment: I used Safari for download